# How to create a custom manager for related objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these related models and one has a custom manager

```
class Device(Model):
    name = CharField()

class DeviceSettingManager(Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

class Setting(Model):
    name = CharField()
    value = CharField()
    device = ForeignKey(Device, related_name='settings')

    objects = DeviceSettingManager
```

but when I run Django shell, I see the "RelatedManager" manager being used

```
>>> d = Device.objects.all()[0]
>>> type(d.settings)
django.db.models.fields.related.create_foreign_related_manager..RelatedManager
```

How do I get the DeviceSettingManager to be used for settings for the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind the result from calling `type()` on the manager, the `DeviceSettingManager` is actually in use. You can check this by doing:

```
class DeviceSettingManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def manager_status(self):
        print("Device Setting Manager is Active")
```

And calling:

```
>>> d = Device.objects.all()[0]
>>> d.settings.manager_status()
Device Setting Manager is Active
```

Even if you explicitly pass a manager to the related object, like:

```
>> d.settings(manager="settings_objects")
```

And of course:

```
class Setting(Model):
    name = CharField()
    value = CharField()
    device = ForeignKey(Device, related_name='settings')

    settings_objects = DeviceSettingManager() # Notice the parenthesis
```

The `class` of the manager will still be shown as: `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager`

Never mind the `class` name.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get `AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute` error when I try to call a manager method.